# Missing PS.exe alias

Tags: windows, powershell, alias

My Windows 11 Enterprise installation is missing the `PS.exe` alias for Powershell. When I try to run any command starting with "PS" for powershell to execute, I get an error that it is unrecognized or cannot be found.

This is a new problem; I have definitely used PS.exe in the not-too-distant past. I still have the Powershell executables at "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" and "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" (as well as in a few "C:\Windows\WinSxS..." locations, according to my Voidtools Everything Search results). So that all looks normal.

I have run Windows Update, `sfc.exe /scannow`, and `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` with no results. I can still launch a powershell instance by typing "powershell" into Windows Search or the `Win`+`R` Run Menu; it's *just* the PS alias that has suddenly gone missing.

I'm wracking my brain trying to figure out what happened. And even if I never learn *why* it disappeared, I would at least like to re-create it properly, if anyone can describe where it is supposed to be.

Comment: sp are you expecting to run (from another shell like cmd) something like `ps Get-ChildItem c:\ ` ? can you give us an example? I do know that the above invocation results in a `'ps' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` error for me. note that in powershell itself, `ps` is an alias for `Get-Process`. what shell do you want to execute powershell from using this alias?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Locate the powershell exectuable. Your search results seem correct, but please open the directory and check if the files are there.

**2.** Add the folder containing the .exe file to the system PATH variable. Copy the location and append it to the end of the variable value. The best method is to open the window where you can modify the system variables, copy the PATH variable value into a notepad, append the folder location, then copy it back to the variable value.

**I recommend editing the System variables, not the User variables!**

Be careful not to delete the current value of the PATH variable or the variable itself!

Based on your search result, I think you will need to append this (quotation marks included):

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\"
```

**3.** Copy and rename the powershell.exe to ps.exe   . You will have both powershell.exe and ps.exe. It isn't the best solution, and it prevents windows updates updating powershell correctly, but it should work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your Windows 11 Enterprise does not have a PS.exe alias for PowerShell, there is nothing wrong with it, since PS.exe was never a standard alias for PowerShell.